# sql query for Running balance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

i am still new to sql, i will need your help, i have a table that look like this

```
ses_date          trx_no        amount
02-04-2014       27487776I      1000
03-05-2014       27485776Y      -500
01-02-2014       65474645H      4500
09-01-2014       65474656D     -3400
```

and i will need an output like this

```
ses_date        trx_no        amount   Debit     Credit        Balance
02-04-2014       27487776I      1000     0.00      1000.00       1000
03-05-2014       27485776Y      -500    -500       0.00          500
01-02-2014       65474645H      4500    0.00       4500.00       5000
09-01-2014       65474656D     -3400    -3400.00   0.00          1600
```

just like a statement of account but in my own case i dont have debit and credit separately, they are together.

Thanks so much for your help and support, you are the best. my DBMS is microsoft SQL server 2008. i try to use this query

```
SELECT ses_date, trx_no, amount, 
  CASE WHEN amount<0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END debit,
  CASE WHEN amount>0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END credit,
  (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM mytable a WHERE a.ses_date<=mytable.ses_date) balance
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ses_date;
```

but it gives (0.00) ZERO in the balance column all through but the debit and the credit is OK. what will i do.

and when i use the second query

```
select ses_date, 
       trx_no, 
       amount, 
       case
           when amount < 0 then amount 
           else 0
       end as debit,
       case 
           when amount >= 0 then amount
           else 0 
       end as credit,
       sum(amount) over (order by ses_date) as balance
from the_table
order by ses_date
```

the error is

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12 Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

what will i do

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: What are you ordering by? The dates aren't in any order I can see...?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 does not support an `order by` for window functions. But your other solution does work for my example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c552e/3

Answer (score 5):

You didn't specify your DBMS so this is ANSI SQL

```
select ses_date, 
       trx_no, 
       amount, 
       case
           when amount < 0 then amount 
           else 0
       end as debit,
       case 
           when amount >= 0 then amount
           else 0 
       end as credit,
       sum(amount) over (order by ses_date) as balance
from the_table
order by ses_date
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c552e/1

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness since MySQL is not very... ANSI, here's a MySQL version that orders by `ses_date`;

```
SELECT ses_date, trx_no, amount, 
  CASE WHEN amount<0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END debit,
  CASE WHEN amount>0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END credit,
  (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM mytable a WHERE a.ses_date<=mytable.ses_date) balance
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ses_date;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09724/1).